# "Program terminated by uncaught signal" when running Python from TextMate

Tags: macos, python, textmate

When I use <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to run my Python code in TextMate under Mac OS X, I receive the follow output:

```
Program terminated by uncaught signal #10 after 0.32 seconds.
```

However when running my code with <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> in Terminal, it works properly.

Does anyone have a similar problem? How did you fix it?

I had this problem in the past, but after reformatting my Mac, it worked properly again. However I had to reformat my Mac once again and the problem reappeared.

Comment: Do you have multiple installations of Python? What does `which python` give you? Maybe TextMate uses an older version because its PATH isn't set correctly. I've had those problems with Ruby and TextMate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer : )  
I fixed the problem by updating my textmate version.

Comment: @slhck - perhaps you could add that as an answer.

Comment: @DannyStaple I don't particularly feel like adding incomplete solutions as answers. Plus, I don't even think this really answered the OP's problem.